# Unable to start spring batch application on JBOSS

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jboss, spring-batch

I've some isssues to deploy a spring batch application to JBOSS due to:

```
 2019-01-02 16:43:40,076 INFO  [org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) Executing step: [step_init]
2019-01-02 16:43:40,234 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) Encountered fatal error executing job: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not create Oracle LOB; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Couldn't initialize OracleLobHandler because Oracle driver classes are not available. Note that OracleLobHandler requires Oracle JDBC driver 9i or higher!; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.sql.BLOB from [Module "org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" from local module loader @3ab39c39 (finder: local module finder @2eee9593 (roots: )]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler$OracleLobCreator.createLob(OracleLobHandler.java:555)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler$OracleLobCreator.setClobAsString(OracleLobHandler.java:447)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$1.setValues(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:238)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:875)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.persistSerializedContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:233)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.updateExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:146)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext(SimpleJobRepository.java:210)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.updateExecutionContext(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:159)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.scheduler.Scheduler.executeInternal(PalinsestoJobScheduler.java:28)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Couldn't initialize OracleLobHandler because Oracle driver classes are not available. Note that OracleLobHandler requires Oracle JDBC driver 9i or higher!; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.sql.BLOB from [Module "org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" from local module loader @3ab39c39 (finder: local module finder @2eee9593 ]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler.initOracleDriverClasses(OracleLobHandler.java:222)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler$OracleLobCreator.createLob(OracleLobHandler.java:526)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.sql.BLOB from [Module "org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" from local module loader @3ab39c39 (finder: local module finder @2eee9593 )]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler.initOracleDriverClasses(OracleLobHandler.java:204)
        ... 55 more
```

I tried to update oracle driver inside jboss modules directory, upgrading it with ojdbc7-12.1.2.jar driver but it is still not working.

Also, I tried to add a dependencies to oracle driver in org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters and nothing happened.

About pom, these are my dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-ftp</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                <version>11.2.0.4</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.38</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- TEST -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
                <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.197</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

It seems that my scheduler class is broken the application, in particular after jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

```
import com.igt.Constants;
import org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.PersistJobDataAfterExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobLocator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;

@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class Scheduler extends QuartzJobBean {

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        try {

            ApplicationContext applicationContext = (ApplicationContext) jobExecutionContext.getScheduler().getContext().get("applicationContext");
            JobLocator jobLocator = applicationContext.getBean(JobLocator.class);
            JobLauncher jobLauncher = applicationContext.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
            Job job = jobLocator.getJob(Constants.BATCH_JOB_NAME);
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
            jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

------------EDIT-------------

Ok, finally I found where is the problem:

```
@Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        // PARTE INIZIALE

        SqlRowSet lDelta = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(sQueryDelta);
        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("queryDelta", lDelta);
        SqlRowSet deltaP= jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(secondDelta);
        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("seconDelta", deltaP);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
```

The problems is related to jdbcTemplate not to Quartz as I supposed. Infact, if I remove from configuration this method (queries) it works without any issue.

Another things, 
I'm using an jndi as db URL, and in the OracleLobHandler.class, the connection is not estabilishied througt oracle driver but with org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapter, and inside that jar there isn't a oracle.sql.BLOB class.

Maybe is it a configuration error?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that the JBOSS server expects to find the Oracle JDBC JAR in the server /lib folder, not your application package.  Add it to JBOSS and see if its class loader finds it appropriately.

Comment: I put the driver inside jboss modules directory, but it won't work

Comment: The class holder is hierarchical: bootstrap, JBOSS, application.  Try adding the JAR to JBOSS so its class loader can find it first.

Comment: Since your `oracle.ojdbc6` artifact is of scope `provided`, it should be present somewhere in your JBoss installation (which depends on JBoss version). Have you tried to put it under `/lib/ext` (not under `/lib` directly)? This thread might help: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/75201

Comment: Yes I tried to the driver inside both of directory lib and lib/ext, but i was unlucky.

Comment: Could you post your answer as an answer instead of in the question so that others will know this has a resolution?